# how to set two different view's id in Carousel at a time?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I implementing a carousel using viewPager in android. I want to set different textview of that two different view at a time. but right now I am able to set only one view's id.How to make it possible in viewpager so that I can set id of both view's . viewpager show only one view at a time..And I want to show view in full screen mode.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be better if you elaborate properly. I am not able to understand your question.

Comment: I want to show two different view using carousel and for that I am using viewPager..but viewPager shows only one view at a time...and I want to set textId of both view's at a time..

Comment: is it you want title for your View pager's Pages.?